# How to run alias analysis (AAManager) with the new pass manager in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'm trying to use alias analysis in a pass written for the new pass manager in LLVM.

```cpp
  PreservedAnalyses run(Module &m, ModuleAnalysisManager &mam) {
    auto &aa = mam.getResult<AAManager>(m);

    analysis(aa, m);

    return PreservedAnalyses::all();
  }
```

In my pass, I use `mam.getResult` (which appears to be equivalent to `getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>()` for the old pass), however, the pass manager wants me to register the analysis first:

```
Assertion `AnalysisPasses.count(PassT::ID()) && "This analysis pass was not registered prior to being queried"' failed.
```

I couldn't find any documentation on how to do that. The closest I came to the solution was [this question](https://groups.google.com/g/llvm-dev/c/JbMAyEcsoHI/m/s7UqE33cDQAJ) on the mailing list, but the response wasn't very helpful.

How do I register the analysis pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out alias analysis cannot be run in a module pass (it's a function level analysis).

From LLVM's page on the new pass manager:

> The analysis manager only provides analysis results for the same IR type as what the pass runs on. For example, a function pass receives an analysis manager that only provides function-level analyses.

Workaround:

```cpp
  PreservedAnalyses run(Module &m, ModuleAnalysisManager &mam) {
    // Get the functional analysis manager from the module analysis manager
    // which has access to the function level analyses
    FunctionAnalysisManager &fam =
        mam.getResult<FunctionAnalysisManagerModuleProxy>(m).getManager();

    assert(not fam.empty());

    // Iterate over each function and get the Alias Analysis for that 
    // particular function
    for (auto fi = m.begin(); fi != m.end(); ++fi) {
      auto demangledName = demangleSym(fi->getName().str());
      auto &aam = fam.getResult<AAManager>(*fi);
      analyseFunc(aam, *fi);
    }
  }
```